# Ionic 2 : *ngFor with an object

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, pipe

I use Ionic 2 and I try do display content of a key-value array. I use an object.

To display my collection, I use a pipe in my html. 
There is my html :

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let event of this.pdata.array | mapToIterable">Toto</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

My pipe code :

```
import {Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

type Args = 'keyval'|'key'|'value';

@Pipe({
  name: 'mapToIterable',
  pure: true
})
@Injectable()
export class MapToIterablePipe implements PipeTransform{
  transform(obj: {}, arg: Args = 'keyval') {
    return arg === 'keyval' ? Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({key: key, value: obj[key]})) :
        arg === 'key' ? Object.keys(obj) :
            arg === 'value' ? Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]) : null;
  }
}
```

Problem : I set my 'array' with an async method, but my pipe is load only one time. So my 'array' isn't empty but my 'toto' aren't display.

My async method is set in a provider. It set my 'array' after a query to an web service. My page constructor call the provider's function to set the 'array', and display the variable in the view.

There is my provider code (p-data.ts) :

```
getDatas() : void {
    let url: string = [MY_URL]
    this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe( res => {
      for (let i: number = 0 ; i < res.events.length ; i++) {
        let object: any = res.events[i].data;

        let data_guid  : string = 'fr_medicalEvent_' + object.id;

        this.array[data_guid] = new CData(data_guid, object.name, object.old);
      }
    }, error => {});
  }
```

My page .ts file :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import {NavController, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {PData} from "../../providers/p-data";
import {DetailsMedicalEventPage} from "../details-medical-event/details-medical-event";
import {PTranslate} from "../../providers/p-translate";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-to-come',
  templateUrl: 'to-come.html'
})
export class ToComePage {


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public pdata : PData, public translate : PTranslate) {
    this.pdata.getDatas();
  }

}
```

How can I force my pipe to refresh ?

Comment: It would be helpful if your code would show how you use "an async method".

Comment: Yes, please add the code. The description is quite vague.

Comment: I can't find a connection between `getDatas()` and your pipe.

Comment: Updated. I hope it will be helpfull this time.

Comment: My pipe doesn't call methode getDatas(). The .ts file of my page call it.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If the pipe returns a `Promise` or `Observable`, then you need to use the `|async` pipe like</strike>

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let event of this.pdata.array | mapToIterable | async">
```

**update**

The problem is that you modify an existing array (`this.array[data_guid] = ...)`. Angular won't recognize this as change and won't update the view. Either you make your pipe impure

```
@Pipe({name: "...", pure: false})
```

which harms performance, or you replace the array with a different one after you updated it

```
this.array[data_guid] = new CData(data_guid, object.name, object.old);
this.array = this.array.slice();
```

which may also be expensive depending on its size.

Comment: My pipe doesn't return promise. I make my call in a provider.

Comment: If you make an async call in your pipe you need to return a `Promise` or `Observable`. It's highly unlikely that you'll get around that.

Comment: I have an error when I try to use slice() in my object. : "Property 'slice' does not exist on type '{ [guid: string]: CData; }'.".

I tried to make my pipe impure but it doesn't work : My page is blocked (infinite loop I think) and my 'toto' aren't displayed.

Comment: Ok, if it's an object (naming an object `array` is a bit confusing ;-) ) you might need to use `var tmp = this.array; this.array = {}; Object.assign(this.array, tmp);` I think it would be better to rethink your data structure and perhaps use observables to actively notify about model changes.